# Strange problem with git repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-status

I just upgraded to OSX Lion on my Mac and I aquired a strange problem with a git repo. I have my .vim files under version control with a number of plugins configured as git submodules. After upgrading, I ran a `git status` command into my .vim directory and got the following:

```
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
```

Does anyone know what my problem is? I searched the above error message on Google and SO, but I didn't find any answers. I've also noticed that git seems to be very slow now. Also, I have no other problems in other git repos (expect the slowness problem), which makes me think the problem is not related to Lion. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can fix my .vim repo? Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is some of the trace output requested by drizzd:

```
setup: worktree: /Users/sbrown/.vim/bundle/supertab  
setup: cwd: /Users/sbrown/.vim/bundle/supertab  
setup: prefix: (null)  
trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain'  
trace: run_command: 'status' '--porcelain'  
trace: exec: 'git' 'status' '--porcelain'  
setup: git_dir: .git  
setup: worktree: /Users/sbrown/.vim/bundle/surround  
setup: cwd: /Users/sbrown/.vim/bundle/surround  
setup: prefix: (null)  
trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain'  
trace: run_command: 'status' '--porcelain'  
trace: exec: 'git' 'status' '--porcelain'  
setup: git_dir: .git  
setup: worktree: /Users/sbrown/.vim/bundle/tasklist  
setup: cwd: /Users/sbrown/.vim/bundle/tasklist  
setup: prefix: (null)  
trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain'  
trace: run_command: 'status' '--porcelain'  
trace: exec: 'git' 'status' '--porcelain'  
setup: git_dir: .git  
setup: worktree: /Users/sbrown/.vim  
setup: cwd: /Users/sbrown/.vim  
setup: prefix: bundle/vim-colors-solarized/  
trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain'  
trace: run_command: 'status' '--porcelain'  
trace: exec: 'git' 'status' '--porcelain'
```

Comment: You mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456683/why-do-i-get-fatal-git-status-porcelain-failed didn't help?

Comment: And the slowness might be explained by some git bash prompt configuration side-effet (http://superuser.com/questions/31744/how-to-get-git-completion-bash-to-work-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still not entirely clear though. Are there aberrant .git files sprinkled though my submodules? I took a look and I didn't see any such files in two or three submodules.

Comment: sure, I was only referring to those questions to check if they could give you any lead.

Comment: Hmmm, all my submodules do have .git directories. Does git put .git directories in each submodule or is this my problem?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/git-easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules. You can try with just one repo, to see if Git remains slow.

Comment: Which git version? Please retry with "GIT_TRACE=2 git status" and post the output. Thanks.

Comment: thanks drizzd. i'm running git 1.7.4.4. do you want the whole trace output? its very long, i posted some of trace output above.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, the only way I could correct the problem was to remove all submodules and then reinstall them.

Comment: Worked here. `rm` the submodule(s), and the run `git submodule init` and `git submodule update`.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone else, I just encountered the same issue and found that running `git init` in the project root fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your git-project (or at least one of your submodules, if you have some) became corrupted. This means that some of the files in your `.git`-folder(s) are corrupt or missing.

#### Fix git-repo

As Jordan mentioned: Go to your root and run `git init`. Then try `git status` again.

#### Fix submodules

If this doesn't work, navigate to your submodule-folder(s) and try `git init` again. Go back to root and run `git status`.

#### Why is it broken?

One answer could be, that there are problems with the access-permissions. Maybe you're working with several users on the working copy?

Another answer could be some kind of sync-software like **OwnCloud**, **Dropbox**, **Google Drive** or like in my case **BitTorrent Sync**. My working copies are located in the sync-folder, which is synced between my computer at work and at home. This causes some issues with permissions.

Hope it helps.