# Failed submodule GIT

Tags: git

I was just trying to copy my files to the newly created local git repository and stage them. But when i tried `git status` what i get is:

```
fatal: Unknown index entry format 2e650000
fatal: 'git status --porcelain=2' failed in submodule vendor/dektrium/yii2-rbac
```

I red some answers but didn't realise how to fix it. Saw the `git mv` command but i don't want to move the module nowhere. How should i fix this? Thank you in advance! 
P.S. The php framework is Yii2, if that matters somehow.

Comment: possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109232/git-fatal-unknown-index-entry-format-61740000

Comment: Nope. The asnwer from this question doesn't help me.

Comment: What commands you run exactly? with which order?

Comment: 1. `git clone '" url from the remote repo "` 2. coping the files 
3. `git status`
And the error occurs.

Comment: @TomaTomov I suggest test it again. After cloning run `git status` to verify first step. Also check `.git` folder and `.gitmodules` files does not replace at step 2. Moreover, again run `git status` at last step. Also check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456683/why-do-i-get-fatal-git-status-porcelain-failed). Hop it helps.